# Hiveql query to get non matching records from two columns

Tags: hiveql

I have 3 tables A,B,C. All the tables have memberid in common. A has a measure id which is a universal id. B has a groupid which is same as group number in C.

I want to write a query where I want to get measure id,member id, groupid and group number for only those member ids where group id <> group number.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Have you tried writing an HQL query? What did it (not) do when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 Select A.id ,B.group_id ,C.group_number ,C.member_ids
 from
 A join B on (A.member_ids = B.member_ids)
 right join C on (B.member_ids = C.member_ids and B.group_id != C.group_number)
```

Comment: But right join will populate NULL on the left column if there is no match. So I am thinking it would be inner join with Where clause as b.groupid <>c.group_number.

Comment: the reason behind the right join is you want only those member ids where  group id &lt;&gt; group number so that condition is on right side table that&#39;s why I used right join and obviously its shows null when condition is not fullfill so we have to used `where member ids is not null` or inner join also works.

Comment: Thanks Sahil! Appreciate your help!